# Linking container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I try to run an instance with 2 containers, 1 container with mysql and other with node.

In **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
api:
  build: ./server
  ports:
    - 8001:8001
  links:
    - mysql:mysql

mysql:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: ghostDB
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  volumes:
    - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Dockerfile of **server/**:

```
FROM node:0.12

ENV PORT 8001
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE ghostDB
ENV MYSQL_USER root
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD root
ENV MYSQL_HOST mysql
ENV MYSQL_PORT 3306

ENV API_DIR /usr/src/server-celerative

COPY . \${API_DIR}

WORKDIR \${API_DIR}

RUN npm install

RUN node index.js
```

**index.js**

```
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'mysql',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'ghostDB'
});
```

But i have got output:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mysql
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
    --------------------
```

I don't understand why not work.

Anybody help?

**NOTE:** I use boot2docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose v1 cannot ensure that the mysql process is fully started and initialized before starting the node container. As a result, your node container is responsible for testing if mysql is yet available and for waiting/retrying until it is available.

You either do this with node in your application ([pooling-connections](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections) might be the way) ; or provide a boostrap shell script that will test the mysql connection and once available will start node.

Comment: I think my problem is not the code else the link of docker-compose. I Cannot connect with 'mysql' host because the container host is not accesible?. Also, i tried changing the code, and doesn't work :/

Comment: isn't that the purpose of `depends_on` or the link syntax for compose v1?https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/#links ie it determines container startup based on that

Comment: in compose v1, the `link` directive hints docker-compose on the start order of containers, but won't ensure a service is ready to serve requests in a container before starting the next one. In compose v2, the `depends_on` syntax was introduced and, for the starting order, works the same way as `link`. Since compose v2.1 you can ensure a service is ready before starting the dependee container ; for that you have to use a combination of [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dependson) and [`healthcheck`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck)

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `container_name: mysql` in the mysql section after `image: mysql`.

The following Bash code could be added to be sure that the 3306 port is open:

`while ! ( exec 2>/dev/null ; echo > /dev/tcp/mysql/3306 ) ; do sleep 1 ; done`